# Adding active class to first item in wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I created slider in wordpress on category and post thumbnail.

I tried to add active class to first item in my loop, but loop show this class in all items.

How can I fix that ?

Here is my loop:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <?php
        $c = 0;
        $class = '';
        query_posts('category_name=slider&showposts=3');
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            $c++;

            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
            $url = $thumb['0'];

            if ( $c == 1 ) $class .= ' active';
                ?>
                 <div class="item <?php echo $class; ?>">
                     <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                     <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h2><?php the_content() ?></h2>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <?php
        endwhile;endif;
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>

</div>
```

http://pastebin.com/R5XA3ik9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this

```
 if ( $c == 1 )
    $class = ' active';
 else
    $class='';
```

**OR**

just in a single line

```
$class = ($c == 1) ? 'active' : '';
```

Answer (score 5):

The other answer are right,

You can make this code nicer with

```
$class = ($c == 1) ? 'active' : '';
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$class` variable still has the value from the first "round".
(Moreover, since you're using `.=` it will become `active active ...` nth times)
You need to add an `else` statement in order to remove the old value.

```
if ( $c == 1 ) $class = ' active';
else $active = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

Please Try It.

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <?php
        $c = 0;
        $class = '';
        query_posts('category_name=slider&showposts=3');
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            $c++;

            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
            $url = $thumb['0'];

            if ( $c == 1 ) $class .= ' active';
            else $class = '';
                ?>
                 <div class="item <?php echo $class; ?>">
                     <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                     <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h2><?php the_content() ?></h2>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <?php
        endwhile;endif;
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try with this

`

```
<?php
    $c = 0;
    $class = '';
    query_posts('category_name=slider&showposts=3');
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $c++;

        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
        $url = $thumb['0'];

        $class = ($c == 1) ? 'active' : '';
            ?>
             <div class="item <?php echo $class; ?>">
                 <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                 <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h2><?php the_content() ?></h2>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <?php
    endwhile;endif;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

<?php
    $c = 0;

    query_posts('category_name=slider&showposts=3');
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

$class = '';
            $c++;

```
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
        $url = $thumb['0'];

        if ( $c == 1 ) $class .= ' active';
            ?>
             <div class="item <?php echo $class; ?>">
                 <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                 <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h2><?php the_content() ?></h2>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <?php
    endwhile;endif;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```